# ajaxForm plugin keeps redirecting to action page ignoring the return false;

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajaxform

I have a simple form that gets submitted when a user clicks open in the file browse window once they have completed selecting an image.

My HTML looks like something below.

```
<form id="imgForm" action="action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="fileUpload btn btn-lg btn-primary">
            <span>Choose File</span>
            <input id="imageToBeUploaded" type="file" class="upload" name="image"/>
        </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$("body").on('submit', '#imgForm', function(){
    $(this).ajaxForm({target:'#uploadStatus'});
    console.log("submitting...");
    return false;
});

/* Uploading Profile BackGround Image */
$('body').on('change','#imageToBeUploaded', function() {
    //submit the form
    $("#imgForm").submit();
});
```

My issue is that the form gets submitted but redirects to the action.php page with response. I was hoping to stop the redirect from happening while getting back a response on the current page instead. return false; doesn't seem to be working as per documentations at http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxSubmit

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please note that I have to support IE8/9 which means formData is out of the question!

Thank you.

Comment: try this `$(this).ajaxForm({target:'#uploadStatus',success:       function(data){console.log(data);return false;}});`

Comment: you need to make sure you are including are necessary jQuery and JavaScripts files. Are you doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this JavaScript/jQuery code and manage with your server script.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
           /* Uploading Profile BackGround Image */
            $('#imageToBeUploaded').on('change', function() {
                //submit the form
                $("#imgForm").submit();
                alert('Form submitted');
            });
            $('#imgForm').ajaxForm({
                target:'#uploadStatus',
                beforeSubmit:function(){
                    alert('File uploading...');
                },
                success:function(){
                    alert('File uploaded');
                },
            });
        });
```

Good Luck ['}

Comment: should have mentioned that it needs to be IE9 compatible. So formData is out of the question :(

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this code:

`window.location.href` it's a property that will tell you the current URL location of the browser. Changing the value of the property will redirect the page.

```
$("body").on('submit', '#imgForm', function(){
var a;
var b;
window.location.href = "../currenturl.htm?parameter1="+a+"&parameter2="+b;
or
window.location.href = "../currenturl.htm";
//where your browser need to stay(current) url should be mentioned here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The page you've referenced is about `$(this).ajaxSubmit(options);` and not `$(this).ajaxForm(options);`. Have you tried `$(this).ajaxSubmit(options);`? The two are not synonymous. You seem to be mixing up their implementations.

Per the documentation, here is how to use `ajaxSubmit()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#imgForm').on('submit', function(){
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({target:'#uploadStatus'});
        console.log("submitting...");
        return false;
    });

    $('#imageToBeUploaded').on('change', function() {
        //trigger submit event
        $("#imgForm").submit();
    });
});
```

And `ajaxForm()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#imgForm').ajaxForm({target:'#uploadStatus'});

    $('#imageToBeUploaded').on('change', function() {
        //trigger submit event
        $("#imgForm").submit();
    }); 
});
```

You don't want to use delegated events unless you really have to. If the form is loaded after the DOM ready event, then by no means use delegated events.

Answer (score 0):

from: [Prevent page reload and redirect on form submit ajax/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567486/prevent-page-reload-and-redirect-on-form-submit-ajax-jquery)

```
$("body").on('submit', '#imgForm', function(event){
    $(this).ajaxForm({target:'#uploadStatus'});
    console.log("submitting...");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

/* Uploading Profile BackGround Image */
$('body').on('change','#imageToBeUploaded', function(event) {
    //submit the form
    $("#imgForm").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
           /* Uploading Profile BackGround Image */
            $('#imageToBeUploaded').on('change', function() {
                //submit the form
                $("#imgForm").submit();
                alert('Form submitted');
            });
            $('#imgForm').ajaxForm({
                target:'#uploadStatus',
                beforeSubmit:function(){
                    alert('File uploading...');
                },
                success:function(){
                    alert('File uploaded');
                },
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this:

use **$(this).closest("#imgForm").submit();**

instead of: **$("#imgForm").submit();**

```
$('#imageToBeUploaded').on('change', function() {
     //submit the form
 $(this).closest("#imgForm").submit();
     $("#imgForm").submit();
 });

    $('form#imgForm').on('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).ajaxSubmit({ 
                    url:   'upload', 
                    uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete){ 
                       //display status
                        $(".progress-bar").width(percentComplete + '%');
                        $('.progress-bar').html(percentComplete+'%');
                    },
                    success: function(response){
                        alert('Success');
                    },
                    error: function(response, status, e){
                        alert('Oops something went.');
                    },
                    resetForm: true 
                });
        });
```

You need this in your script tag <https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/source/browse/trunk/struts2-jquery-plugin/src/main/resources/template/js/plugins/jquery.form.min.js?r=1645>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#imgForm").ajaxForm({
        target:'#uploadStatus'
    });
});

$('body').on('change','#imageToBeUploaded', function() {
    //submit the form
    $("#imgForm").submit();
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use event.preventDefault(); instead of return false with jQuery

```
$("body").on('submit', '#imgForm', function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    $(this).ajaxForm({target:'#uploadStatus'});
    console.log("submitting...");
    return false;
});
```

Alot of people might not agree with me but returning false is usually saying something failed, while your ajax submit might actually have worked just fine, so it could bring mixed results to your original caller. In this case it does't matter but I will only return false if something actually failed or went wrong or when a boolean is requested. If empty result I would return null, rather then false. Just convictions I suppose..

not sure why you have 2 js functions but you could combine both functions as :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    /* Uploading Profile BackGround Image */
    $('body').on('change','#imageToBeUploaded', function() {
        //submit the form
        $('#imgForm').ajaxForm({target:'#uploadStatus'});
        console.log("submitting...");
    });
 });
```

Comment: Hi DarkMukke thanks for your help! This solution however stops the form from submitting altogether :(

Comment: i'm not completely familliar with the plugin, i will look through it's source, give me a min. Could you tell me what version you are using ?

Comment: DarkMukke Thanks again! It seems I am using the latest  * version: 3.51.0-2014.06.20

Comment: My edit might not solve the problem but it might not have the problem at all. You don't really need to submit your form at all. eg : https://jsfiddle.net/4efzz2pp/1/

Comment: Yes it seems the form is not getting posted at all in this case. Rather unfortunate :/

Comment: @BaconJuice do you need to submit the form ? can you not just use the second example i gave you there or check the JS Fiddle ?

Comment: it seems that the form is not posting at all with that solution

Comment: @BaconJuice i think you misunderstand, the form doesn't need to submit at all, you can post ajax requests when ever you want it doesn't need to be a form submit.

Comment: It needs to be posted if a file is being uploaded. I have to support IE 8&9 so formData is out of the question thus my decision to use ajaxForm plugin

Comment: @BaconJuice You can just submit the form manually with jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: "returning false is usually saying something failed" that is not what the return is saying at all. Since the function is asynchronous the return actually doesn't matter. return ends the asynchronous function, that is all. http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js search for jQuery.event