# What is error in code below while submitting AJAX from handeled by PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a file called `try.php` where there is code below having all javascript, PHP and html file in itself.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    echo "hello";
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Submit Form Using AJAX and jQuery</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" id="myForm">
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="email">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    <div id="display"></div>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 
        window.history.back();
        var form_Data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "try.php",
            data: form_data,
            cache: false,
            success:function(response){
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The target of above code is just to submit form without reloading the page simply using `AJAX` and the form data should be handled by `php` here just `echo "hello"`. The above code works fine it submits and php handles all properly but page is reloading. What should be the change in code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent page reload and redirect on form submit ajax/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567486/prevent-page-reload-and-redirect-on-form-submit-ajax-jquery)

Comment: Yes, everything works fine in above code but I could not find why page is reloading? There is `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the reloading.

Comment: why do you call         window.history.back();

Comment: Why `window.history.back();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); //prevent default action 

        var form_Data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "try.php",
            data: form_Data,
            cache: false,
            success:function(){
                alert("hello");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I recommend explaining where the problem was instead of simply pasting the correct code. This way more people can learn from the error.