# How do I post form data with fetch api?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api

My code:

```
fetch("api/xxx", {
    body: new FormData(document.getElementById("form")),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        // "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
    method: "post",
}
```

I tried to post my form using fetch api, and the body it sends is like:

```
-----------------------------114782935826962
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

test@example.com
-----------------------------114782935826962
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

pw
-----------------------------114782935826962--
```

(I don't know why the number in boundary is changed every time it sends...)

I would like it to send the data with "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", what should I do? Or if I just have to deal with it, how do I decode the data in my controller?

---

To whom answer my question, I know I can do it with:

```
fetch("api/xxx", {
    body: "email=test@example.com&password=pw",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    method: "post",
}
```

What I want is something like $("#form").serialize() in jQuery (w/o using jQuery) or the way to decode mulitpart/form-data in controller. Thanks for your answers though.

Comment: What is issue with using `FormData`?

Comment: I want to post it as "email=test@example.com&password=pw". Is it possible?

Comment: *“I don't know why the number in boundary is changed every time it sends…”* – The boundary identifier is just a random identifier, it can be anything and does not have any meaning on its own. So there is nothing wrong with choosing a random number there (which is what clients usually do).

Answer (score 385, accepted):

To quote [MDN on `FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) (emphasis mine):

> The **`FormData`** interface provides a way to easily construct a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and their values, which can then be easily sent using the `XMLHttpRequest.send()` method. **It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to `"multipart/form-data"`**.

So when using `FormData` you are locking yourself into `multipart/form-data`. There is no way to send a `FormData` object as the body and *not* sending data in the `multipart/form-data` format.

If you want to send the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` you will either have to specify the body as an URL-encoded string, or pass a [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object. The latter unfortunately cannot be directly initialized from a `form` element. If you don’t want to iterate through your form elements yourself (which you *could* do using [`HTMLFormElement.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements)), you could also create a `URLSearchParams` object from a `FormData` object:

```
const data = new URLSearchParams();
for (const pair of new FormData(formElement)) {
    data.append(pair[0], pair[1]);
}

fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    body: data,
})
.then(…);
```

Note that you do not need to specify a `Content-Type` header yourself.

---

As noted by [monk-time](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6270692/monk-time) in the comments, you can also create `URLSearchParams` and pass the `FormData` object directly, instead of appending the values in a loop:

```
const data = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(formElement));
```

This still has some experimental support in browsers though, so make sure to test this properly before you use it.

Comment: You can also use an object or just `FormData` in the constructor directly instead of a loop: `new URLSearchParams(new FormData(formElement))`

Comment: @monk-time At the time of writing that answer, the constructor argument to `URLSearchParams` was *very* new and had very limited support.

Comment: sorry, that wasn't a complaint, just a note to everyone who will read this in the future.

Comment: I just wasted a couple of hours pulling my hair out after I missed reading this line:

`Note that you do not need to specify a Content-Type header yourself.`

Leaving a note for people searching for this in future.

If you are using flask, posting multipart FormData using fetch api and not receiving any data, remove your Content-Type header.

Comment: @Prasanth You may specify the content type yourself explicitly, but you have to pick the *correct* one. It’s easier to just leave it off and have `fetch` take care of it for you.

Comment: what node library should I use for URLSearchParams?

Comment: @chovy `URLSearchParams` is built into most modern browsers as a global object and also works from Node.

Comment: if you need to post FormData there is no need to use `URLSearchParams`

fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    body: new FormData(form_element),
})

Comment: @El Did you read the answer (and the question actually)? Sending `FormData` directly implies a specific content type.

Comment: @shahrozbutt That assumes you are using jQuery which is not really common anymore today (and still wasn’t _that_ common back in 2017). The question actually specifically asks for a solution **without** using jQuery.

Comment: isn't `multipart/form-data` better (more efficient) than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? I mean when would you want to use later over the former?

Comment: Today I got the experience that I have to use 

'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

together with URLSearchParams()

otherwise it creates no FormData.

Comment: I get a `PayloadTooLargeError` error

Comment: @chovy That’s the server refusing the request.

Answer (score 223):

**Client**

Do not set the content-type header.

```
// Build formData object.
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name', 'John');
formData.append('password', 'John123');

fetch("api/SampleData",
    {
        body: formData,
        method: "post"
    });
```

**Server**

Use the `FromForm` attribute to specify that binding source is form data.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleDataController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create([FromForm]UserDto dto)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}

public class UserDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: While this works, this does not send the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is what OP is asking for.

Comment: For me, it worked when i **REMOVED** `Content-Type` from the header and let the browser do it automatically. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't set 'Content-type' for Fetch, its gonna set it as `multipart/form-data`, which is what it should be for form data! Then you can use `multer` in expressjs to parse that data format easily.

Comment: This worked for me. I'm using Laravel 8 (Sanctum) as backend.

Comment: Using laravel 9 (passport) and also worked for me

Comment: it makes sense...

Answer (score 94):

Use `FormData` and `fetch` to grab and send data

```
fetch(form.action, {method:'post', body: new FormData(form)});
```

```js
function send(e,form) {
  fetch(form.action, {method:'post', body: new FormData(form)});

  console.log('We send post asynchronously (AJAX)');
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="myapi/send" onsubmit="send(event,this)">
    <input hidden name="csrfToken" value="a1e24s1">
    <input name="email" value="a@b.com">
    <input name="phone" value="123-456-789">
    <input type="submit">    
</form>

Look on chrome console>network before/after 'submit'
```

For `x-www-form-urlencoded` use `URLSearchParams`

```js
function send(e,form) {
  fetch(form.action, {method:'post', body: new URLSearchParams(new FormData(form))});

  console.log('We send post asynchronously (AJAX)');
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="myapi/send" onsubmit="send(event,this)">
    <input hidden name="csrfToken" value="a1e24s1">
    <input name="email" value="a@b.com">
    <input name="phone" value="123-456-789">
    <input type="submit">    
</form>

Look on chrome console>network before/after 'submit'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for and it's amazing how easy pure JavaScript can be nowadays. Just look at that beautiful **1 liner** `fetch` code that `post` the `<form>` data, I'm still amazed how I found this. Bye bye jQuery.

Comment: Not important here at all but there's a typo in hidden input's name. For anyone who wonders why that input is there, `csrf` stands for Cross-site Request Forgery.

Comment: The option `method: 'post'` has no effect since the browser will use the method attribute of the `form` passed to `FormData`. Even when the method attribute is not defined in `form` the browser will fallback to default `GET` method.

Comment: @MarcoMannes if your remove `mehtod:'post'` from `fetch` params in snippet above, you will get `Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.` exception. If you remove `method="POST"` from html in above snippet, the `method:'post'` (in fetch params) will have effect - and browser will send POST - I check this by modify this snippet and using chrome>network tab (so actually we can remove this from html... but I will left it)

Comment: Is form.action the endpoint url?

Comment: @ShivamSahil in this example yes

Comment: It's incomplete, You must then pass that `FormData` to the constructor of `URLSearchParams` to create the body, as written in the selected answer.

Comment: The `new formData(form)` only picks up elements with a `name=...` attribute !

Answer (score 50):

You can set `body` to an instance of `URLSearchParams` with query string passed as argument

```
fetch("/path/to/server", {
  method:"POST"
, body:new URLSearchParams("email=test@example.com&password=pw")
})
```

```js
document.forms[0].onsubmit = async(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const params = new URLSearchParams([...new FormData(e.target).entries()]);
  // fetch("/path/to/server", {method:"POST", body:params})
  const response = await new Response(params).text();
  console.log(response);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="email" value="test@example.com">
  <input name="password" value="pw">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `Reflect.apply(params.set, params, props)` is a particularly unreadable way of saying `params.set(props[0], props[1])`.

Comment: @poke `Reflect.apply(params.set, params, props)` is readable from perspective here.

Comment: What if I send a **5MB image** file over *body:new URLSearchParams("img="+my5MBimage)* ?

Comment: @PYK In that case you can't use application/x-www-form-urlencoded but multipart/form-data: [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)

Answer (score 22):

With fetch api it turned out that you do NOT have to include headers "Content-type": "multipart/form-data".

So the following works:

```
let formData = new FormData()
formData.append("nameField", fileToSend)

fetch(yourUrlToPost, {
   method: "POST",
   body: formData
})
```

Note that with axios I had to use the content-type.

Comment: I am sending a file and some data from React to Flask and it didn't work until i removed Content-type. Thank you :)

Answer (score 9):

"**body:FormData**" works but there're type complains, also "**FormData**" sets multipart headers. To make the things simplier, "**body:URLSearchParams**" with inline construction and headers set manually may be used :

```
function getAccessToken(code) {

    return fetch(tokenURL, 
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',                 
               'Accept': '*/*' 
            },            
            body: new URLSearchParams({
                'client_id':clientId,    
                'client_secret':clientSecret,
                'code':code,    
                'grant_type': grantType,
                'redirect_uri':'',
                'scope':scope
            })
        }
        )
    .then(
        r => return r.json()
    ).then(
        r => r.access_token
    )
  }
```

Comment: This is much nicer for when your data is already an object. Nice!

Answer (score 6):

To add on the good answers above you can also avoid setting explicitly the action in HTML and use an event handler in javascript, using "this" as the form to create the "FormData" object

Html form :

```
<form id="mainForm" class="" novalidate>
<!--Whatever here...-->
</form>
```

In your JS :

```
$("#mainForm").submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const formData = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(this));
  fetch("http://localhost:8080/your/server",
    {   method: 'POST',
        mode : 'same-origin',
        credentials: 'same-origin' ,
        body : formData
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.text()
    }).then(function(text) {
        //text is the server's response
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

‍These can help you:

```
let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("name", "John");
            formData.append("password", "John123");
            fetch("https://yourwebhook", {
              method: "POST",
              mode: "no-cors",
              cache: "no-cache",
              credentials: "same-origin",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "form-data"
              },
              body: formData
            });
            //router.push("/registro-completado");
          } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more explanation as to what you changed that made it better

Comment: `no-cors` and the Content-Type header are almost certainly wrong.

Answer (score 4):

There are instructions on the MDN that the browser will automatically handle `Content-Type`:

> [A request will also automatically set a Content-Type header if none is set in the dictionary.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#body)

So we don't need to specify 'content-type' when we send a fetch request.

```
const formData = new FormData();
const fileField = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');

formData.append('username', 'abc123');
formData.append('avatar', fileField.files[0]);

fetch('https://example.com/profile/avatar', {
  method: 'PUT',
  body: formData
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(result => {
  console.log('Success:', result);
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

If set `content-type` in headers. Browser will not try to split formdata in request payload.

I'm using [fathcer](https://github.com/fatcherjs/fatcher) to handle FormData, the same behavior as XHR.

```
import { formData } from '@fatcherjs/middleware-form-data';
import { json } from '@fatcherjs/middleware-json';
import { fatcher } from 'fatcher';

fatcher({
    url: '/bar/foo',
    middlewares: [json(), formData()],
    method: 'PUT',
    payload: {
        bar: 'foo',
        file: new File()
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
})
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

@KamilKiełczewski answer is great if you are okay with the form data format being in form multipart style, however if you need the form submitted in query parameter styles:

> You can also pass [FormData directly to the URLSearchParams constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) if you want to generate query parameters in the way a  would do if it were using simple GET submission.

```js
        form = document.querySelector('form')
        const formData = new FormData(form);
        formData["foo"] = "bar";
        const payload = new URLSearchParams(formData)
        fetch(form.action, payload)
```

Answer (score -1):

With Content-Type: "mulitipart/form-data"

```
const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("form"))

fetch("http://localhost:8000/auth/token", {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
  }
})
```

With Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

```
const formData = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(document.getElementById("form")))

fetch("http://localhost:8000/auth/token", {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }
})
```