# Empty values when posting FormData-object via fetch-api in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, fetch-api, form-data

I have written a React-component which should be used for all forms in my application. When a certain button is clicked I make some validation and finally I want to post the form to the server.
This is what this part currently looks like:

```
// get what should be submitted
const formData = new FormData(theForm)); // theForm is the DOM-element

//  post the form-data element
fetch(theForm.action,
    {
        credentials: "include", //pass cookies, for authentication
        method: theForm.method,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
            //"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: formData
    })
    .then(res => console.dir(res))
    .catch(reason => console.error(reason));
```

The shown snippet work fine in `Chrome`. However, in `IE11` it is not. 
On the other hand, when uncommenting the `Content-Type` header, it will also break in `Chrome`.

As found https://stackoverflow.com/a/46642899/615288 it is always `"multipart/form-data"`. But even if I set it to `multipart/form-data` the values are not send to the server.

I am using the FormData polyfill from https://github.com/jimmywarting/FormData as well as `whatwg-fetch`.

I don't see what is going on here as FormData should work in IE since version 9.

Sidenote: When commenting out the whole header-part it still works in `Chrome` as the browser seems to guess the correct ones (as it can be seen in the developer-tools)

Answer (score 1):

Somebody reported this to me today in the repo.

https://github.com/jimmywarting/FormData/issues/44

Apparently "IE fail to set Content-Type header on XHR whose body is a typed Blob" that's why you get wrong content-type header. updating the version to might 3.0.7 fix this

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, but after much frustration I found out that appending an extra field to the `FormData` object suddenly all the fields appeared on the server.

```
const formData = new FormData(theForm);

// this somehow makes it work
formData.append('fakefield', 'nothing to see here!');

fetch(theForm.action).then(/* do the stuff */);
```

I don't know why it works, but before I added that line the server received `{}` as the request body and afterwards it received `{ myformfield: 'myvalue', myotherfield: 'myothervalue', fakefield: 'nothing to see here!' }`

Hope this can save someone a bit of frustation :)

Comment: What you are passing in "theForm", I am facing same issue.