# How to send FormData from javascript to ASP.NET Core 2.1 web API using fetch

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, fetch

i'm trying to create a form that sends FormData object to API controller that serializes the data to Article class, but i cannot get it to work. I have already tried the things that are commented.

this is my HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="postArticle()">
<input type="type" name="Title" value="" />
<input type="type" name="Content" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

this is my JS:

```
<script>

var postArticle = () => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var Article = new FormData(this.event.target);
    console.log([...Article]);
    fetch('/api/Articles', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/formdata',
            //'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: Article
        //body: JSON.stringify(Article)
    })
}
</script>
```

Controller:

```
    // POST: api/Articles
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostArticle(Article article)
    {
        string name = article.Title;
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        _context.Article.Add(article);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok();
    }
```

and my Article class:

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does happen? Does you F12 browser dev tools show anything in the console or network tab? Does your controller get hit at all? More input....

Comment: yes, sorry i forgot to mention that, the request returns 400, and the response is : {"":["The input was not valid."]}

Comment: Two things: you are not posting an Id field, which is required; and you could try to use `PostArticle([FromForm] Article article)`

Comment: I think the answer here may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640024/how-do-i-post-form-data-with-fetch-api

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Ok, i added [FromForm] and i made new model where there is not Id at all, now the request returned 200 (ok) but none of the form data actually came into the article model (Title= null, Content=null)

Comment: You should see in the browser's developer console what's actually being sent

Comment: **Works now!** The solution is to not set any content-type headers along with adding the [FromForm], thank you all contributing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works now! The solution is to not set any content-type headers along with adding the [FromForm], thank you all contributing.

part of the solution was at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640024/how-do-i-post-form-data-with-fetch-api)

these are the changes:

```
var postArticle = () => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var Article = new FormData(this.event.target);
    console.log([...Article]);
    fetch('/api/Articles', {
        method: "POST",
        body: Article
    })
}
```

```
// POST: api/Articles
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostArticle([FromForm]Article article)
    {
        string name = article.Title;
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        //_context.Article.Add(article);
        //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(); //CreatedAtAction("GetArticle", new { id = article.Id }, article);
    }
```

Comment: You should post the final edited code rather than just point at another question