# How to recive uploded file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, react-redux

i have a redux-from submission, console log look like this

```
{
  id: "x", 
  parentId: "b", 
  editing: true, 
  logo: FileList, 
}
```

Logo **FileList** contains my uploaded file name and file, i think

```
0: File(19355) {name: "11964821.jpeg", lastModified: ......
```

using **fetch** to send to nodejs, image contain my files and above data

```
function Update(image) {

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { ...authHeader(), 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: JSON.stringify(image)
    };
    return fetch(`${apiUrl}/API`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse)
    .then( data => {  return data; });
}
```

but this data not receiving nodejs, because is tried re.file etc.. its shows undefined

```
app.post('/image', upload.single('logo'), function (req, res, next) {

})
```

---

include **formdata**

```
  const onSubmit = (image, dispatch)=>{

    var formData = new FormData(); 
    formData.append('logo',image.logo[0]);

    var imageNew = {...image,formData};

    dispatch(imageActions.companyProfileLogoUpdate(imageNew)) ;  
  }
```

now **log** is

```
formData: FormData {}
id: "5c66478b0814720a4365fe72"
logo: FileList {0: File(19355), length: 1}
parentId: "5c66478b0814720a4365fe71"
```

Comment: what is upload.single('logo')?

Comment: multer file upload package for nodejs

Comment: are you using multer to save image

Comment: FileList is a single image or multiple images

Comment: yes... using multer to save image,  backed part is ok  because its working fine with postman

Comment: FileList - single image

Comment: have you defined storage location/directory for upload

Comment: yes.. its working fine using postman,, but when we come to redux form upload  not working

Comment: you are not sending formData in request i think

Comment: do not use JSON.stringify(image)

Comment: wait .. i will update my question with from data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move formData to fetch file and remove header content type, Try this

```
function Update(image) {

var formData = new FormData(); 
formData.append('logo',image.logo[0]);  

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { ...authHeader() },
        body: formData
    };
    return fetch(`${apiUrl}/API`, requestOptions).then(handleResponse)
    .then( data => {  return data; });
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  fileList[0] to image.logo[0], working fine  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('logo' , {{your image file}}

// upload file as 
let result = await sendServerRequestForForm(url,formData);


function sendServerRequestForForm(url,data) {
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve($.ajax({
        url,
        method : 'POST',
        data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {
            return data
        },
        error: function (err) {
            try{
                let responseStatus = err.responseJSON
                // watch your response
            }catch (e) {
                console.log('Field to get response');
            }
        }
    }));
});
return promise

}
```

Comment: he is specific about using `fetch api`. fetch and jquery ajax differ a lot

Comment: :( yes fetch api

Comment: ok @david you could try below answer 
i just forgot you are using fetch :)

Comment: you can also ajax any problem with this ?

Comment: will try , but prefer solution for this :(

Comment: fetch API should also work i dont know where its going wrong.. 
for fetch API do not set header i think this help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640024/how-do-i-post-form-data-with-fetch-api

Answer (score 1):

for fetch API you can try this

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('logo', fileList[0]);

fetch(url, {
method: 'post',
body: data,
})
.then(…);
```

Comment: are you sure Content-Type' is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded ?

Answer (score 0):

**First** thing is for using `fetch api` for post `content-type header` should match typeof `body`. since your body is `json stringified` your **contentType** header should be `'application/json'` . [more about this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Uploading_JSON_data) .

**Second**. since you want to upload an image which a `file` you should use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) without requirement of setting contentType: like **below**:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('logo', image.logo[0]);

const requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData
};

fetch(`${apiUrl}/API`, requestOptions)
.then(handleResponse)...
```

Comment: my file in image.logo[0], is it okey to join var imageNew = {...image,formData}; like this ?

Comment: i dont think so. `formData` is not simple object `its instance of formData `

Comment: i dont think so. `formData` is not simple object `its instance of formData ` .to add data, you need to call `formData.append('logo', fileList[0])`.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: fileList is not defined

Comment: @david dude, i wrote `fileList` just to signify whatever variable list you are using. on top of it these random guys have blindly copied my answer and pasted. one of those is accepted too :/