# Is that possible to use features of form(validation) but send data with onclick instead?

Tags: javascript, html

On my page, I would not use PHP to send emails (please, do not comment) then came to a solution with external service which is invoked by fetch. That is why I submit my form data with `onclick` function; and this `onclick` is bound to button. Practically this `onclick` doesn't use form features, it simply grabs form's data by its ID.

That button stays outside of the form. Needless to say that in that case, I do not benefit from typical form features like required and pattern validate.

Is there a simple way to have a button which sends data by `onclick` and also triggers form validation? By form validation, I mean usual internal HTML
validation. Of course I could develop validation within `onclick` function body, but that is not what I am looking for - I'd like to use form's features instead.

Comment: Please insert your [code](/help/mcve) to the question! Without code it's hard to help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661187/form-serialize-javascript-no-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to throw your submit button back into your form so you can take advantage of all those built-in features, and then you're going to use the `submit` event on your form and then take advantage of [`fetch`, `URLSearchParams`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46642899/2535504), and [`FormData`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26501400/2535504) as follows:

```
// HTML

<form id="form">
    <!-- inputs go here... -->
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

// JavaScript

const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

    // prevents default submission so we can do our magic
    e.preventDefault();

    // build request
    const formData = new FormData(form);

    fetch('some/endpoint', {
        method: 'post',
        body: new URLSearchParams(formData),
    });

    // do something else...

});
```

These are all modern best practices, but they aren't great with compatibility. You might have to look at `XMLHttpRequest` instead of `fetch` and even looping through form elements instead of using `FormData`, but this should put you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you. It looks good, I will test it on afternoon. That way you avoid using onclick which as I see is in conflict with type='submit'. Yes, it looks very  promising