# Convert request to Nodejs in fetch to React-native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, request, fetch

I need to convert the following request, which is the following code for react-native:

Nodejs:

```
const request = require('request');

var areaRiservata = {
    url: "https://www.iliad.it/account/",
    method: "POST",
    followAllRedirects: true,
    jar: true,
    form: {
        "login-ident": config.iliad.username,
        "login-pwd": config.iliad.password
    }
}

exports.Login = function(callback) {
  request.post(areaRiservata, function (err,res,body) {
    if (String(body).match(/ID utente o password non corretto./g) != null) {
      //Login fallito, restituisco errore
      callback('Errore durante il login. ID utente o password non corretto.');
    } else {
      //Login effettuato, restituisco il sorgente della pagina
      callback(body.replace(/<\/span> \//g, ' /').replace(/GB<br>/g, 'GB</span>'));
    }
  });
};
```

I have tried this, but it seems to not work.

React-native

```
fetch('https://www.iliad.it/account/', {
      method: 'POST',
      header: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'login-ident': ident,
        'login-pwd': pwd,
      }),
    })
      .then(response => response.text())
```

For example the fetch does not contain these fields, as I can do.

```
followAllRedirects: true,
jar: true,
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I post form data with fetch api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640024/how-do-i-post-form-data-with-fetch-api)

Comment: Is different, because the fetch does not have the following fields.
followAllRedirects: true,
jar: true,

Comment: Could you inspect the requests in the logs as `cURL`? Maybe you will see what is missing from the RN request?