# Requesting access token in DocuSign - Node.js

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I am following this documentation: https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token

I am trying the following for the callback API:

```
router.get('/authGrantReturn', function(req, res){
    let query = req.query; 

    console.log("code: " + req.query.code);
    console.log("status: " + req.query.state);
    console.log("in authGrantReturn");

        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    try{


    let bodyData = {
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            code: req.query.code
        };


        console.log( "========code======")
        console.log(  req.query.code)
        console.log( "========/code======")

        let combination = `${integrationKey}:${secretKey}`;
        let b64Combination = Buffer.from(combination).toString('base64');

        console.log("combination "+ combination)
        console.log("b64Combination "+ b64Combination)

   fetch('https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + b64Combination, 

        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
       body: bodyData
   })





    /* fetch('https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token?grant_type:authorization_code&code='+b64Combination,{
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ${b64Combination}', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',  'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'}
    }) */
    .then(function (res) {
```

etc....

The above is the callback function called by url that looks like this: https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=7c2b8d7e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cda8a50dd73f&state=a39fh23hnf23&redirect_uri=http://example.com/callback/

However I am getting "Bad Request" , the req.query.code is correct, I am not sure about the combination.

What am I missing?

Comment: Per stackoverflow policy, please ask additional questions as new questions. StackOverflow is not a message board. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please upvote all useful answers, including those to others' questions. And please be sure to check/accept the best answers to your own questions! Many thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a visual review of your code and have several comments:

### Readability

I suggest that you use await instead of dealing with the promise objects explicitly. Note that your code will need to be in an `async` function to use await, but this is easy to do.

### Sending form data via Fetch

I think your specific problem is that you're not sending the form data correctly. See [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46640744/64904).

#### Caveat: the following code uses the FormData object. It always creates `multipart/form-data` requests. If this doesn't work then you can create the form-data either via the URLSearchParams object or explicitly. See the reference.

Untested code:

```
const bodyform = new FormData();
bodyform.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
bodyform.append('code', 'req.query.code');

console.log( "========code======")
console.log(  req.query.code)
console.log( "========/code======")

let combination = `${integrationKey}:${secretKey}`;
let b64Combination = Buffer.from(combination).toString('base64');

console.log("combination "+ combination);
console.log("b64Combination "+ b64Combination);

let res = await fetch('https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token',{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + b64Combination },
    body: bodyform
});

console.log( "========Results========"); console.log (res);
```

### Check state

It is important to check that the `state` value you receive back from DocuSign is the same one you sent when you re-directed the user's browser to the DocuSign identity service. The state value [prevents CSRF attacks](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2/oauth-state). It must be a new nonce value--random and unguessable.

### Try / catch

You should wrap the fetch call in a try/catch block. This will work correctly with await to catch errors.

### Use a library

The security experts recommend that you use a library whenever you're implementing a security-related process (where libraries are commonly available).

For Node.js, the [passport](http://www.passportjs.org/) library is very popular and there's a [passport strategy](https://github.com/docusign/passport-docusign) for DocuSign. See this [example](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant) of using it.

See the [index](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant/blob/master/index.js) and the [DSAuthCodeGrant](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant/blob/master/lib/DSAuthCodeGrant.js) supporting object which fetches the user's name, account id, API base url, etc.

Comment: Thank you Larry, I am looking into your git example.

Comment: Another question: 
The https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token is sometimes returning "html string" that includes a consent/acceptance form, how can I display it to the user? I have tried res.writehead() and res.send() ; I am not sure if this is the right response to get from that API.