# Using FormData() inside fetch api is not working

Tags: javascript, fetch, form-data

I read all over but couldn't find the answer.

When I use FormData(), it returns status 404 bad request.

However, if I pass the data (hardcoded) as in const requestBody (example below), it works perfectly.

This is my code:

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("nickname", "johxns");
    formData.append("password", "john_password");
    formData.append("email", "john@server.com");

    // If I do it this way, and assign this to body inside fetch, it works perfectly
    // const requestBody = '{"nickname": "johxns","password":"john_password","email":"john@server.com"}';

    fetch("http://localhost:5000/create_user", {
        // if instead of formData, I assign requestBody to body, it works!
        body: formData,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        method: "POST"
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
    }).then(function(data){
        console.log('data', data);
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.err(err);
    });
```

I already tried with URLSearchParams, but still couldn't make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried converting formData to json?

Comment: Well, if it works one way and not the other, I'd stick with the way that works... What's the question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` if you're not sending json. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46640744/3688864) answer, you don't need to set the `Content-Type` header.

> body data type must match "Content-Type" header

[Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 0):

You should either send json data if you set `Content-Type` to `application/json` or not set any Content-Type if using FormData API since the fetch function is able to determine the correct `Content-Type`.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for more informations.