# In react nativ fetch method is not working

Tags: php, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to fetch data from from php api here is the code of api

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST)){
        $array = ["name" => "vasu" ,"json" => "created at 2021"];
     print_r(json_encode($array));    
    }else{
        $array = ["error" => 22];
        print_r(json_encode($array));
    }
?>
```

Here is the code of my react nativ fetch method

```
 fetch(url,{
     method : "POST",
     body : JSON.stringify({
       name : "vasu"
     })
   })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(json);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
```

Output

### {"error":22}

It means I can't get anything in $_POST
How to fix this problem

Comment: You're posting the data in the **body** of your request. You will need to use `file_get_contents('php://input');` to access it on the server side. You will have to use `FormData` to post data the way you you're trying to access it.

Comment: To add into @codemonkey comment, checkout it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640024/how-do-i-post-form-data-with-fetch-api

Answer (score 0):

Hi there the Issue was that you are using **JSON.stringyfy** while declaring your body which is not correct that's why it is not taking the value of body and giving you error

you should be use that as

```
 fetch(url,{
 method : "POST",
 body : {
   name : "vasu"
 }
})
 .then((response) => response.json())
 .then((json) => {
  console.log(json);
 })
 .catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```