# How to display my realtime voice prediction in flask web without reload the page?

Tags: html, flask, voice-recognition, ludwig

Because i want to create realtime face and voice recognition to lock the door using flask web app with ludwig toolbox. If i click the record button the webpage will record my voice for 1 sec and after that my voice will get predicted and display the data as table or dict.

So my question is how to display my predict voice as table or dict to webpage (HTML) without reload the page because if i reload the page my face recognition program will getting reload too and make my program start from beginning.

**Python file**

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template
    from threading import Timer
    import webbrowser
    import speech_recognition as sr
    from ludwig.api import LudwigModel

    to_predict={"audio_path":["C:/Users/Laptop/Desktop/TUGAS_AKHIR/Fix_ludwig_project/Uploads/speech.wav"]}

    # load the model
    model_path = "results/experiment_run/model"
    model = LudwigModel.load(model_path)

    def execute():
        result = model.predict(data_dict=to_predict)
        if (result['label_predictions'] == ['Dwi'] ).any():
            print ('Door Open')
            z = "DOOR OPEN"
            alhasil = z
            return alhasil
        else :
            print ('Door Lock')
            y = "DOOR LOCK"
            alhasil = y
            return alhasil

    def speech():
        with mic as source:
            while True :
                audio = r.record(source, duration=1)
                try:
                    with open('Uploads\speech.wav', 'wb') as f:
                        f.write(audio.get_wav_data())
                        
                    result = model.predict(data_dict=to_predict)

                    print(result["label_predictions"])
                    hasil= result.to_html()

                    execute()
                    return hasil
                    
                except ValueError:
                    print ('Programe error')

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    mic = sr.Microphone()

    app=Flask(__name__)
    @app.route('/')
    def home():
        return render_template("spchrecog.html")

    @app.route('/record/')
    def record():
        return render_template("spchrecog.html", hasil=speech(), alhasil=execute())
        
    def open_browser():
        webbrowser.open_new('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        Timer(0.5,open_browser).start();
        app.run(port=5000)
```

**HTML file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Voice Recognition Ludwig</title>
<style>
a{
margin:0% 44%;
}
body{
background-image:url({{url_for("static",filename="templates/back.jpg")}});
width:auto;
}
img{
border: 4px solid black;
border-radius:130px;
width:10%;
height:10%;
}
.p1 {
color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
text-align:center;
font-size:25px;
font-family:"Lucida Console", Courier, monospace;
font-weight:bold;
}
.p2 {
color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
text-align:center;
font-size:40px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
}
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  position: relative;
  animation-name: mymove; 
  animation-duration: 5s; 
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes mymove {
  from {left: 0px;}
  to {left: 500px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="p1">VOICE RECOGNITION WITH LUDWIG</p>
<br><br>
<a href="/record/"><img src="{{url_for("static",filename="images.png")}}"></a><br>
<br>
<hr>
            {% if hasil %}
                <h2>  Hasilnya adalah : </h2>
                {{ hasil | safe }}
            {% endif %}
<br>
<hr>
            <div>
                <p class="p2"> {{ alhasil }} </p>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How you are sending data to flask app now. Please tell what you have tried

Comment: So i have tried to record my voice for 1 sec and after that the voice will get predict with ludwig toolbox. After that the result will  displayed to terminal and continue to html file to get display. so my problem is how to display the predict in html without reload the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

To update a Website without reloading you need to use JavaScript which then optimally contacts a Flask endpoint that returns the data.

Comment: Do you have any example how can the data displayed without reload the Website using Javascript? Because i'm have already searched and did'nt find the sample program.  

I'm really need help because im the new person who just learning programming language.

Comment: I answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67862006/15011621). Maybe this helps.