# How to send FormData (POST) via xhr or fetch()?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I want to translate the jQuery code into plain javascript.

I have this function above.

```
$.post(
    "/product/getList",
    {
        id: id,
        product_id: product_id.value,
    }
).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

this will send data as FormData `code=test&product=227`

I tried with xhr

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/product/getList", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    id: id,
    product_id: product_id.value,
}));

xhr.onload = function() {
    let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(data)
}
```

and fetch

```
fetch("/product/getList", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
    body: JSON.stringify({
        id: id,
        product_id: product_id.value,
    })
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response)
});
```

but both functions send data as Request Body `{"code":"s","product":"227"}`

How i can send also FormData via `xhr` and `fetch()` ?

**---------------------- Updated: ----------------------**

This is the FormData when i use $.post()

[image]

This is my FormData using

```
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
},

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("id", id);
formData.append("product_id", product_id);
```

[image]

and try header

```
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
},
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I post form data with fetch api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640024/how-do-i-post-form-data-with-fetch-api)

Comment: Unfortunately not.. i will update my question and post the difference between both FormData

Comment: Thats in linked question, create `FormData` object, populate it with data (id and product_id) and then use it in body/send argument.

Comment: To POST like jQuery above just create FormData object. Dont set content type header, or set it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `FormData` object and fill it with your props.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id', id);
formData.append('product_id', product_id.value);

// and send it

xhr.send(formData);

// OR

fetch("/product/getList", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
})
```

But remember that `formData.append(..)` adds one more field even if it already exists in `formData` so you can use `formData.set(..)` instead to ensure your `formData` has unique fields only.

You can find some docs on [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)