# I am passing javascript variable to php using fetch api method post but in php file i am getting error: undefined array key 'data'. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, php, html, server-side, client-side

**------html code------**

```
<html>
<body>
 <textarea id="my-textarea"> </textarea>
 <button onclick="_post_text_area_()" id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
</body>
<html>
```

**------javascript code------**

```
# get value of textarea
var textarea = document.getElementById("my-textarea");

function _post_text_area_() {       
    var data = textarea.value;
    # show textarea value to console
    console.log(data);

    # pass data variable using fetch api POST method
    fetch('_process.php', {
             method: 'POST',
             body: 'data=' + data
       })
       .then(function (response) {
          return response.text();
       })
       .then(function (data) {
           console.log(data);
           });
}
```

**--- _process.php ---**

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['data'];
echo "Received data: " . $data;
?>
```

I am getting an error in _process.php file:  Undefined array key 'data'. I think, i am getting this error because my javascript function is not able to create post request but I don't know the exact reason why i am getting this error.

I have tried different technique like ajax XmlHttpRequest to pass data variable to _process.php file but i got the same error.

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("my-textarea");

var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit-btn");

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  var data = textarea.value;

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

      console.log(this.responseText); // Print the response from the server

    }

  };

  xmlhttp.open("POST", "process.php", true);

  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  xmlhttp.send("data=" + data);

});
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("my-textarea")` there is no element with that `id`. Did you `console.log` your `data` to see what it contains? Did you use your browser's DevTools/Network tab to see what gets sent/returned?

Comment: “Undefined *array* 'data'” or “Undefined *array key* "data"”?

Comment: @brombeer this is not the problem. There was some mistake in my question. Now i have modified my question. Thanks for your comments. Now you can see understand my question properly.

Comment: @fusion3k i am getting this error: Undefined array key 'data' In php file. I am getting this error in  $data = $_POST['data'];

Comment: Have you looked at [FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46642899/231316) yet?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes sir, I have tried and used FormData but still can't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally preferred to use `FormData` when creating the payload to send via `fetch` - the following does send the AJAX request but fails due to Sandbox limitations.

```js
const d=document;

d.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  if( e.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement && e.target.id=='submit-btn' ){
    let fd=new FormData();
    fd.set('data', d.getElementById("my-textarea").value );

    fetch('_process.php', {method:'post',body:fd })
      .then(r=>r.text())
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(alert)
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea id="my-textarea"></textarea>
<button id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The same code that was originally posted will only work with you set the content type appropriately. The `$_POST` variable was left empty for that reason.

You can change your `fetch` command to the following version:

```
fetch('_process.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: 'data=' + data
 })
 .then(...)
 ...
```

Or, you can use the `application/json` content type in your `fetch` command:

```
fetch('_process.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: 'data=' + data
 })
 .then(...)
 ...
```

... and in your PHP, instead of relying on the `$_POST` object, you do the following instead:

```
<?php
$postedData = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$data = $postedData['data'];
echo "Received data: " . $data;
```