# Async/Await Fetch POST parameters for text/html

Tags: javascript, django, async-await, fetch

How do I `POST` parameters for content type `text/html` without sending it as an object?

In my case I need to send extra data outside of a form read from cookie.

Posting using `body : {}` or `body: JSON.Stringify({})` posts data an object. I want data to be posted as individual values.

```
$(document).on('click', '#update', async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("/getupdate",{
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'text/html; charset=utf-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "country": getCookie("country"),
                "city": getCookie("city").replace(/"/g, ""),
                "action": 1,
                "csrfmiddlewaretoken": $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            }),
        });
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error)
    }
});
```

Got an object instead of individual values -

```
{
    "country": "US",
    "city": "Miami",
    "action": 1,
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "iLoS4Bsgdyc6EhOtQKiiXrIqr9S1eojdhdyEeClA8qI5ei2WpfQQu1JrduLrbndndR"
}
```

Expecting individual values -

```
    "country": "US",
    "city": "Miami",
    "action": 1,
    "csrfmiddlewaretoken": "iLoS4Bsgdyc6EhOtQKiiXrIqr9S1eojdhdyEeClA8qI5ei2WpfQQu1JrduLrbndndR"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "individual values", There is no such a standard format. You have to be clear about what's wrong with `JSON` and why you need such "individual" values. Also, Whats the purpose of having `Content-Type':'text/html;`

Comment: @BadPiggie As a payload, form data. Trying to do async form submit.

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640024/how-do-i-post-form-data-with-fetch-api) contain examples of how to post form data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I post form data with fetch api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46640024/how-do-i-post-form-data-with-fetch-api)

Comment: @BadPiggie Not entirely. In my case I need to send extra data outside of the form read from cookie and token.

Comment: Seems you haven't gone through the answers properly. You can still append anything outside of form like `let formData = new FormData();` then `formData.append('country', getCookie("country"));`

Answer (score 0):

Adding my comment as an answer, Since you have mentioned you want to submit a `form-data`. You have to construct [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) , Instead of [JsonString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
$(document).on('click', '#update', async () => {
    try {
        // Construct form data
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append("country", getCookie("country"));
        data.append("city", getCookie("city").replace(/"/g, ""));
        data.append("action", 1);
        data.append("csrfmiddlewaretoken", $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val());

        const response = await fetch("/getupdate",{
            method:'POST',
            body: data,
        });
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in sending the data as JSON string/object there could be other options. Here I have three examples. Sending as:

- text/pain
- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data

Sending the data with the content type `text/html` does not make sense, now that the data has nothing to do with HTML code.

Personally, I would prefer use either the second or third option.

#### Send as text/plain (URI encoded)

This is what I interpret out of your question. You would like to send the data as a plain string. Now, that is a bit messy with line breaks and characters like `"`, so you need to [encode the data as URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). In this case the server has no chance of interpriting the data/string, therefore this option is not a good idea.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#update', async() => {
  let data = `"country": ${getCookie("country")},
              "city": ${getCookie("city").replace(/"/g, "")},
              "action": 1,
              "csrfmiddlewaretoken": ${$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()}`;

  try {
    const response = await fetch("/getupdate", {
      method: 'POST',
      body: encodeURIComponent(data)
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
});

function getCookie(str) {
  return "some string";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="csrfmiddlewaretoken">
<button id="update">Update</button>
```

#### Send as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

This is the default content type when you POST data using an ordinary HTML form. If there are no files that need to be send, this is would be the preferred option. The server will be able to interpret the data as if it was a HTML form sending the data.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#update', async() => {
  let data = new URLSearchParams();
  data.append('country', getCookie("country"));
  data.append('city', getCookie("city").replace(/"/g, ""));
  data.append('action', 1);
  data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val());

  try {
    const response = await fetch("/getupdate", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      body: data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
});

function getCookie(str) {
  return "some string";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="csrfmiddlewaretoken">
<button id="update">Update</button>
```

#### Send as multipart/form-data

This is content type used when you POST data including files in a HTML form. The server will be able to interpret the data as if it was a HTML form sending the data.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#update', async() => {
  try {
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append("country", getCookie("country"));
    data.append("city", getCookie("city").replace(/"/g, ""));
    data.append("action", 1);
    data.append("csrfmiddlewaretoken", $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val());

    const response = await fetch("/getupdate", {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
});

function getCookie(str) {
  return "some string";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken">
<button id="update">Update</button>
```