# res.send in API redirects to API URL

Tags: angularjs, node.js, post

I'm working on an API project which communicate with another API, my front is AngularJS. I take back the project, I don't understand the whole of it yet...

Here is my current situation:
I'm on `http://localhost:3004/#/references/add/pictures`
When I post a picture, it return me the name of the picture hashed with random characters, this is what I want. BUT when picture is posted, it redirects me to the API's URL where the picture is posted which is `http://localhost:3000/api/pictures`
I would like to stay on my first page and just get the name of my picture to use it in my form. 
I identified the lines which sends the picture:

```
const router = require('express').Router()

// Uploads file to DB
router.post('/', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  res.send(res.req.file.filename);
});
```

I'm not a crack in node.js, just learning, I hope you understand my question which is:

How can I do to post a picture, get the picture name generated (to use it), and stay on my page `http://localhost:3004/#/references/add/pictures` ?

Thanks for replies

Comment: what's the `router` variable? I believe what you're looking for is https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: const router     = require('express').Router()

Comment: Thx for replying
My post function works,my problem is an automatic redirection at each post, and I don't want this redirection, u have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, redirection to an Iframe doesn't redirects you bto another URL, works fine, thx to Issa Chanzi
[How to submit html form without redirection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983603/how-to-submit-html-form-without-redirection)