# Hide form after submit JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html `form` inside the `table` and i want to make it disappear after the user submits the `form`

**Form:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
    <h6>Have Discount Coupon? Apply it here...</h6>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div id="form">
      <form class="coupon" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="coupon" placeholder="Enter Coupon Code" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="submit" name="coupon" value="Apply Coupon">
      </form>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>

<script type="text/Javascript">
  $('#form').submit(function() { 
    $(this).hide(); 
  });
</script>
```

After the submission, the `form` is still visible and nothing happening.

Answer (score 2):

You have to *prevent the default action* first in order to hide the form using `event.preventDefault()`

Further if you're working on a commercial level and you want your form to be submitted *without redirection*, then you can use [XHR request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983603/how-to-submit-html-form-without-redirection)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
    <h6>Have Discount Coupon? Apply it here...</h6>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div id="form">
      <form class="coupon" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="coupon" placeholder="Enter Coupon Code" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="submit" name="coupon" value="Apply Coupon">
      </form>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>

<script type="text/Javascript">
  $('#form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ... XHR request to submit form
    $(this).hide(); 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: How the form will be submitted if you prevent the event?

Comment: By using [XHR request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983603/how-to-submit-html-form-without-redirection)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the selector:

```
$('#form')
```

The `<form>` element does not have the attribute `id="form"` — (that's the `<div id="form">` - not a form and therefore not submittable) — all you need to do is target the actual `<form>` element. Change your code to this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) { //NOTE: Removed "#" 
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide(); 
})
```

And it will work:

```js
$('form').submit(function() {
  $(this).hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
    <h6>Have Discount Coupon? Apply it here...</h6>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div id="form">
      <form class="coupon" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="coupon" placeholder="Enter Coupon Code" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="submit" name="coupon" value="Apply Coupon">
      </form>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @Strange I've just added a working example - did it fix your problem?

Comment: Actually OP wants only the form to disappear. In your case, the table also disappears (or technically, the page redirects)

Comment: @rv7 Of course, because a form submit reloads the page.

Comment: @rv7 Fixed now, any better?

Comment: Change `$(e)` to `e` at `$(e).preve...`

Comment: @rv7 Sure, still a newbie to that kind of thing

Comment: its hiding the entire table after submission.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Problem in the approach that You use.**Each time you run click the submit button in the page your page gets reloaded **this will hide the form when you click and again render the whole page from the begining**. because of that you want be able to get what you want.Instead try to send data using Ajax by having a button rather than using the default form submission approach

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will do the same and let you know if it worked.