# How to submit form without redirecting to its action page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form in my HTML which it redirects to another site, but I don't want it to go to that action page but instead I just want to display something.

I tried putting a javascript onclick as redirect() and still it's not working

```
<form id="gform" method="POST" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" data-email="myEmail@gmail.org"
            action="https://script.google.com/a/symposium.co/macros/s/sdkhkjhKJDFHEfskhdFFDfsEFSEsxvbTj/exec">

...........

 <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="redirect()" required>Send Report</button>

        </form>
```

Comment: Live in the now. Use AJAX.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to submit html form without redirection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983603/how-to-submit-html-form-without-redirection)

Comment: Or you can submit the form to a hidden iframe.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX

Comment: Good chance you will  need to use a proxy to submit to remote site using ajax if it is not CORS enabled

Comment: `https://script.google.com/a/symposium.co/macros/s/sdkhkjhKJDFHEfskhdFFDfsEFSEsxvbTj/exec` gives me page not found.

Comment: I just edited its link for privacy purposes,, but it's working. My only problem is that I dont want to go to that page after clicking submit.

Comment: Don't use a form or `eventObject.preventDefault()` within your onclick function. By the way you should separate your JavaScript from your HTML. Also, just submitting a form to another site is not testing for a result. Use AJAX. Might as well use their [API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/).

Comment: Thanks I already got it. I use jquery ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `onsubmit` and `event.preventDefault();` on form:

```
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); doSomething()">
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

and JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSomething() {
    //AJAX request...
}
</script>
```